# How to get a page access token from a page admin, without scripts

Tags: facebook-graph-api

For a client, I have to show some pictures of people who like their facebook page, on their website. For this, I assume I need an page access token. I need this only once I guess, so how could I easily get this from my client, without having to program? E.g. can I give the client a URL which then gives him an access token, which he can give to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically you can but it defeats the purpose of authentication by passing the access token in plain sight.

You will first need the dialog/oauth url to get the user access token with `manage_pages` permission

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=manage_pages`

Then you request the access token for the page

`https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN`

The way to ensure the token would be to program a login page for your client so they can pass the access token securely, then you save the page token to a database.

You are correct that you will only need this once as the page token has no expiry.

In the context of showing pictures of user who like a fan page, this is not possible in the API. You can only do this using the Like Box plugin.